# Is LinearTransformation's matrix a square matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

**Linear Transformation’s confusions.**

---

Is [linear transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map)'s matrix a square matrix?

Some books define linear transformation is $V\to W$, and say linear operator is $V\to V$.

Some books define linear transformation is $V\to V$, and $V\to W$ is linear mapping.

**wiki:**

> In mathematics, a linear map (also called a linear mapping, linear transformation, linear operator or, in some contexts, linear function.

How to understand these terminologies.

Comment: However you call it, a matrix corresponding to a linear map is square iff the map is between vector spaces of the same (finite) dimension. What you wrote some books say in the first line is, imo, the more usual terminology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the confusion with terminology may be the result of the different contexts (and different levels of abstraction) in which "linear maps" are discussed. Furthermore, authors differ in the terminology that they "favor".

From the entry you link to that corresponds to "Linear Map", we have the following:

> In mathematics, a linear map (also called a linear mapping, linear transformation, linear operator or, in some contexts, linear function) is a function between two modules (including vector spaces) that preserves (in the sense defined below) the operations of module (or vector) addition and scalar multiplication.

Your first question seems to concern what we mean by linear maps in the context of maps between *vector spaces*, and in particular, a "linear map" described by multiplication by a **[transformation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix)**.

The matrix $T$ corresponding to sucha linear map is square if and only if the map is between vector spaces with the same finite dimension.

In general, if the dimension of $V$ is $m$ and the dimension of $W$ is $n$, then the matrix corresponding to a linear map $f: V \to W$ is an $\,n\times m\,$ matrix.

If $V$ and $W$ are of finite dimension, and one has chosen bases in those spaces, then every linear map $f:V \to W$ can be represented as a matrix. On the flip side, matrices yield examples of linear maps: if $A$ is a real $n\times m$ matrix, then the rule $T(x) = Ax$ describes a linear map $R^m \to R^n$ (see Euclidean space).

---

Comment: this needs a TU! +1 Wonder if the OP disappeared?

Answer (score 1):

If $V$ and $W$ are different vector spaces then $f:V\rightarrow W$ is called **linear transformation** or **linear map** or **homomorphism** of vector spaces and in the case $V$ and $W$ are the same vector space then  $f:V\rightarrow V$ is called **linear operator** or **endomorphism**.

There's other terminologies in the cases $f$ injective or surjective or bijective map.